# Replace/Generate HTML content in div dynamically | .NET + JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to display/replace the HTML content inside a div according to a pressed pushpin in Bing Maps. I know I should be looking at JQuery **.html()** but I can't see how I can put a variable inside the HTML tags.

Example code:

```
function pushpinClickedCallback(e) {
        if (e.target.metadata) {
            var data = e.target.metadata.title;  <-- how to make this include the JS variable and HTML tags
            $('#infoPane').html(data);
        }
// var e above is a pushpin in Bing Maps, infoPane is the div
```

Every time the callback is fired there is different data to be displayed. Should I even be looking at doing it this way? Or should I create a new div and destroy it each time (inefficient if pressing the same pushpin many times quickly)?

Comment: you'd build the HTML string yourself.  If you are getting the title here, just construct whatever HTML you want... ex: var html_data = "<H1>" + data + "</H1><script>your_script_here</script>";

Comment: Yes, it's actually simple af lol... Guess I was overthinking it a lot from working on it all for so many hours. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `data` will contain a string. Manipulate the string using JavaScript string functions to replace your title string and add whatever HTML tags you need. For example:

```
var data = e.target.metadata.title; // "Pushpin title"
var htmlString = "<div class=\"pin-text\">" + data + "</div>";
$("#infoPane").html(htmlString); // Replace infoPane element contents
```